# Error log - 'PHP Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Catalog_Model_Product' not found in'

Tags: fatal-error, error-log

One of our clients is running a Magento site that experiences intermittent problems where the home-page *half-loads* occasionally.

Investigating `/var/log/httpd/error_log` reveals the following which appears to be the source of the problem:

```
[Sat Feb 28 21:05:45 2015] [error] [client ###.###.#.###] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_Catalog_Model_Product' not found in /var/www/html/app/code/local/TM/Highlight/Block/Product/Abstract.php on line 40
```

The culprit code block in `/local/TM/Highlight/Block/Product/Abstract.php` is:

```
    $this->addData(array(
        'cache_lifetime'    => 86400,
        'cache_tags'        => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::CACHE_TAG),
    ));
```

I've had a quick look at the documentation for the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` class and it does seem that class exists and so does the constant `CACHE_TAG`.

What's going on here? Is it a bug in this `Abstract.php` (which has come from `Templates-Master` at http://www.templates-master.com)? Is the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` class magically being loaded sometimes and not loaded other times for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check if you compilation is enabled and is correctly build?

Maybe a conflict with some other installed modules? You could(on a test environment) disable some modules/cache/compilation and enable developermodus to investigate further.

Maybe you installed a module which adds some magic to the existing autoloader.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen Boersma. I'm relatively new to Magento. How would I go about checking compilation is enabled/correctly built? The odd thing is that the error seems to occur sometimes, but not others. Currently, the error is not triggering, but it was a couple hours ago. Could it be related to PHP running out of memory or something like that?

Comment: Found `php -f compiler.php enable` and some more reading here: http://alanstorm.com/magento_compiler_path

Comment: Output from `php -f compiler.php state` is `Compiler Status: Disabled` and `Compilation State: Compiled`

Comment: Did `php -f compiler.php clear`, `php -f compiler.php recompile` and `php -f compiler.php enable`. The issue has gone away completely now!